# Funciones no definidas en javascript en el "onClick". Página que cambia texto normal a ASCII

Tags: javascript, html5

Es una página con javascript que convierte un texto a ASCII, pero no corre.
He estado intentando corregir el código pero no entiendo cuál es el problema. Despliega todo bien, pero a la hora de usarlo no sirve. Además en las opciones de desarrollador de chrome dice que mis funciones no están definidas en el "onClick()"

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

```
    <script>

        function cifrar(){
            char array[];
            var leer = document.getElementById("1").value;              

            array=leer.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                array[i]=(char)(array[i]+(char)258);
            }
           document.getElementById("2").innerHTML="Chale, chale" +leer;                  
        }

        function decifrar(){
            char array[];
            var leer = document.getElementById("1").value;              

            array=leer.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                array[i]=(char)(array[i]-(char)258);
            }
           document.getElementById("2").innerHTML="Chale, chale" +leer; 


        }

         </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <form>
     <h1>Cifrado</h1>         

     Escriba el Mensaje:<br><br>
     <input type="text" id="1" name="mensaje" rows="10" cols="40">
        <br><br>
        Elige una opción:
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" name="cifra" value="Cifrar" onclick="cifrar()">
        <input type="button" name="decifra" value="Decifrar" onclick="decifrar()"> <br><br>

        <textarea id="2"rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>

    </form>





</body>
```

Comment: Eso no es JavaScript, es una mezcla de JavaScript y Java que no existe. Te recomiendo mirar un tutorial de JavaScript. Lo que quieres se hace mediante métodos como `chartCodeAt` y `fromCharCode`: [ver ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Gugadev/w79m1Lcu/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modifiqué un poco tus funciones, espero y sea eso lo que quieres hacer.

```
function cifrar(){
    var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
        array = [];

    for(var i=0; i < leer.length; i++){
        array[i] = leer[i].charCodeAt( 0 );
    }

    //Se muestra la variable 'array' en lugar de 'leer' para ver el resultado
    document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array;
}

function decifrar(){
    var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
        array = [];

    for(var i=0, char; char = leer[i]; i++){
        array[i] = String.fromCharCode( leer[i].charCodeAt( 0 ) );
    }

    //Se muestra la variable 'array' en lugar de 'leer' para ver el resultado
    document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho, agradecido. Lo malo es que no descifra, sólo lo cifra. @ftorres

Comment: Lo siento no probé la función 'decifrar'.

Comment: Ya la probé, si lo que tu quieres es recuperar el texto ya cifrado, entonces si funciona, solo que imprime los caracteres separador por una coma.